# Erhversstyrelsens CVR-API with elasticsearch and R?

Tags: json, r, elasticsearch, httr

For a while I have been trying to access data from The Danish Company register, which is stores in elastic searchs rest API. I have tried using httr and The elastic package for R with no luck.

I think i have succeded connecting using

```
elastic::connect("distribution.virk.dk/CVR-permanent/", es_port=" ", es_user="username", es_pwd="pass")
```

I can use the `count` function to see the index of companies, participant and production units

```
Count(index="virksomhed")
[1] 1617466
```

The issue comes when I use `Search()`. Below is my input

```
Search(index=virksomhed, q="422900")
```

where 422900 is nacecode. I have tried various type of test with no luck though. Also tried using body copying search JSON search strings.

My result is always the same.

> Error in if (gsub("\.","",ping()$version$number) <500) {: argument is of length zero

Is there Any help out there? Httr jsonlite, anything??

code here

Comment: Have you looked at [elasticsearchr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/elasticsearchr/vignettes/quick_start.html)?

Comment: `elastic` maintainer here: what version of `elastic` do you have? and what version of Elasticsearch are you running

Comment: Is the line of code `Search(index=virksomhed, q="422900")` correct? if so, shouldn't `virksomhed` be quoted? or is it a variable that you've assigned a string to?

Comment: that's a typo, wrote the question on my phone. If I have read the info from the CVR-elasticsearch correctly, it is an index and should be correct. I have the newest version of elastic and the rest api runs on elasticsearch 1.7.4. So quite an old one.

Comment: @KristofferWintherBalling, I have looked at it, but with no result yet. I have managed to import data with httr though. Only issue there is, that the logic of the build up is a bit more tricky. Have you used it with elasticsearchr?

Comment: @KristofferWintherBalling Do you have experience using elasticsearchr and to what extent?

Comment: @ReneKJ Sorry, no experience with elasticsearchr

Comment: Hi @sckott, I have tried using, the elastic package again. I seem to have connected to the database, when putting ping after connect I get a list of json showing the database structure.  When I try to use Search i still get an erro though. although now it's a new error.   `Error in extractr(ver, "[[:digit:]]+")[[1]] : subscript out of bounds`  MY code is   `Search(source="Vrvirksomhed.virksomhedMetadata.nyesteNavn.navn", q="271100", fields="Vrvirksomhed.virksomhedMetadata.nyesteHovedbranche.branchekode", size=50)`

Comment: that's a problem in checking the ES version, what ES version are you running?

Comment: Ah, I see. Well the database is running on a very old version - 1.7.4 I think